# How to check if bootstrap's jquery-plugin is working properly?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to check if `twitter-bootstrap`'s `jquery` plugins are working properly?

Comment: confirm if they are working correctly.

Comment: By working do you mean - working on a browser X, have been downloaded by the client, have defects in the code base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {

    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

}else{

    alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
```

or

```
if (jQuery) {  

   alert("jQuery library is loaded!");

} else {

   alert("jQuery library is not found!");

}
```

Comment: sorry but I am new to front-end stuff. exactly where shud i run this code?

Comment: inside

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

Comment: That doesn't test specifically if twitter's bootstrap has loaded.

You'd have to use something like  if(jQuery().Carousel) {} since bootstrap isn't namespaced as 'Bootstrap'.

Answer (score 1):

A much better answer is already here: [How to check if Twitter Bootstrap is Loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933000/how-to-check-if-twitter-bootstrap-is-loaded). If jQuery is also having problems, such as if the "$" character is not defined when you run the code from the link above, or if you want to check if jQuery itself is loading, try here: [jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. Here is how I can load bootstrap from the CDN or fail to local.

```
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>if ($('body').popover) { document.write('bootstrap loaded from cdn') }
            else { document.write('cdn bootstrap failed, going local');
                   document.write('<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>') }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How to check in Python and Appium if bootstrap.js is properly loaded and working.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please try to read again the rules for posting answers and questions.